# How do I port forward through 3 routers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, port-forwarding

I am trying to port forward for accessing my home automation network remotely, the challenge is how my home network set up...

I have 1 Verizon jetpack mifi 6220L that connects via USB to a craddlepoint MBR1400 (the VZW jetpack turns wifi off and delivers internet via USB only when connected). The MBR1400 has crappy wifi signal so I connected an Ubiquiti Amplifi HD router and Mesh Point. The Amplifi HD router is what everything in my house connects to.

I know how to port forward on all 3 but don't know the exact solution to be able to access my network remotely. Honestly I am really stuck and Im a newb, I've tried port forwarding on just the Amplifi HD with no success. I feel like there is a bigger issue here because of the 3 routers.

BTW...I know that this network is not ideal but honestly its been working really well for over a year.

Thanks for your help,

Rafa

Answer (score 2):

You simply port forward the port on the outermost router to the WAN IP of the router it connects to, and repeat for the middle router.

From the sound of it you could easily get rid if the third router by convering it into an AP (ie ignore/disable its WAN port, disabling DHCP and connect a LAN port to the MBR1400). Simpler, more reliable, not much more work then the extra port forward.